# When do you capitalise the "P" in pokemon?

Tags: capitalization

There have been a lot of articles online of late concerning the release of Pokemon Go. Across different articles, there are different patterns for capitalising the 'p' in pokemon.

I have been taught to use capitalisation when it is a name, but constant use when referring to pokemon as a collective term (I.e. when being used to refer to a group pf pokemon) has made me unsure.

When referring to a group, I have aleays been taught to use lower case, as in

> **"A group of pokemon"**

**What is the correct use of capitalisation, when talking about a made-up species, such as in Pokemon?**

I would think a more concrete rule applies to created names than "whatever the creator uses", and given that anybody can edit the Wikipedia, I do not trust its use of capitalisation. I feel that this *might* be right, but a good answer should tell my the global rule to follow, not "This is what the wikipedia says".

There is not going to always be a "wikipedia page" or "homepage" to check these sort of things, in future cases.

Comment: Every single instance (count 'em - over 500!) of the word [*Pokémon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon) on the relevant Wikipedia page is capitalised. So is every one on [pokemon.com](http://www.pokemon.com/uk/). I don't know what *you* mean by "when referring to pokemon as a collective", but I think you're probably mistaken. Besides, which it's a *Trade Name*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, as in plural.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why not change your comment into a real answer?

Comment: For what its worth, I will not accept an answer that uses the reasoning "the creators and wikipedia said so". I'm sure a properly thought out answer will be of far better quality, though

Comment: @FumbleFingers, youve mostly been able to answer the question, I am not sure what else you don't get. Do I need to better define what a plural is?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92712/what-is-the-plural-form-of-trademarked-product-names-specifically-of-the-term

Comment: What better source is there for correct capitalization rules of a trademarked term other than that creator? You say "I have been taught", but I doubt Pokemon came up in your classroom in this context. What rule are you claiming to apply here? The general case here isn't "made-up species", it's "trademarked names", such as Hondas, to describe a group of Honda Civics.

Comment: @AlannaRose: To be fair, most Brits today (but perhaps not most *Americans*) wouldn't capitalise *hoover the carpet*. And hardly anyone still capitalises *take a couple of aspirin*. But I think *Pokémon* has a long way to go before it attains such status. Even the "elder brother" ***Pacman*** [hasn't got there yet.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pacman%2CPacMan%2CPacman&year_start=1975&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpacman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPacMan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPacman%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Nouns are not capitalized unless they are proper or at start of sentence (has nothing to do with species). Sometimes a proper noun over time becomes so associated with the underlying object that it becomes the main word to describe that object.  When that happens often the capitalization disappears or becomes optional.  The word "thermos" is a good example, it's brand name but often used to refer to any vaccuum bottle in general, and typically not capitalized unless we are talking about a real Thermos brand thermos.  Not sure if Pokemon has reached this status yet but it's close I'm sure.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, it does seem likely that people use lower case colloquially. The question "when do trademarked items not require a capital letter" seems to be "when they have become everyday objects, though the creators might not approve." I mostly found the attitude of this question ridiculous, not the question itself, but it also appears they've significantly improved it.

Comment: @AlannaRose: I (and four others) successfully voted to close the question, and it's not obvious to me why five more users decided to *reopen* it. It's essentially a matter of opinion whether/when this specific word will achieve "generic" status, which is why I think it's Off Topic. But per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Pokemon%2Cpokemon&year_start=1994&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CPokemon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpokemon%3B%2Cc0) it's obviously not there yet (nor *likely* to be, imho), no matter how much OP might wish otherwise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you did not vote to close the question as opinionated. It was closed as inclear.

Comment: I honestly dont care how you capitalise it. **I just want to know the correct way to do so**

Comment: @Timelord64: I don't remember precisely, but you may be right. I *think* I initially closevoted as "Unclear" when I posted my first comment. That was because I didn't fully understand the question (when I do that I normally check back after an edit to see if I should retract). I don't want to get involved in a close/reopen cycle, but now I *do* understand what you're getting at, I would choose POB. Although to be fair, there's so little support for your position (that there should be a "rule", which you'd apparently like to endorse the uncapitalized version) that it's almost "Too Basic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

iT d-pENdZ

People can write and spell and capitalize/capitalise anyway and anyhow they please.

If you want to get to the nitty-gritty, you need to decide the purpose and audience of your writing.

If you are writing informally about Pokémon (note well, the *e* in the word has an [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent) on it, thus *é*), then you can capitalize it as you please. I don't know who told you not to capitalize the word when it refers to a group of pokemon/pokémon, but there is nothing wrong or illegal about either capitalizing or not capitalizing it in this case.

On the official U.S. website for Pokémon, the [Legal Page](http://www.pokemon.com/us/legal/) says

> Pokémon, Pokémon character names, Nintendo 3DS, Nintendo DS, Wii, Wii U, and Wiiware are trademarks of Nintendo.

The *Chicago Manual of Style* (CMOS) (online version) says

> 8.152 Trademarks
>
> **Brand names that are trademarks—often so indicated in dictionaries—should be capitalized** if they must be used. A better choice is to substitute a generic term when available... [emphasis mine]

CMOS continues

> Note also that some companies encourage the use of both the proper and the generic term in reference to their products (“Kleenex facial tissue,” not just “Kleenex”) and discourage turning product names into verbs, but these restrictions, while they may be followed in corporate documentation, are not legally binding. (In fact, Webster’s includes entries for lowercase verbs google and xerox.)

Examples of trademarks from CMOS include *Bufferin (buffered aspirin)*, *Coca-Cola (cola)*, *Jacuzzi (whirlpool bath)*, *Kleenex (facial tissue)*, *Levi's (jeans)* and *Xerox (photocopier)*.

So, following CMOS, one wouldn't say

> There's a bunch of kleenex over there

but

> There's a bunch of Kleenex facial tissues over there.

By analogy, I guess one would say

> There's a group of Pokémon pocker monsters over there.

The APA Style Guide (aka the *[Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association](http://www.apastyle.org/manual/index.aspx))* says to capitalize trade names and brand names. I don't own an APASG, so I got that from the APA Style Blog article "Do I capitalize this word?" ([link](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/02/do-i-capitalize-this-word.html)). The blog contains a chart of "noun types", amongst which is *Product* and that seems what Pokémon falls under, given that that type includes Advil, Xerox, and Prozac (brand names).

Neither source discusses the plural of a trade mark or brand name. Probably for a reason. There is no official, legal plural of a trademark unless that trademark is registered in a plural form.

Pokémon, as far as I can find, has only ever been registered as a trademark in the singular. When I go to the United States Patent and Trademark Office's [Trademark Electronic Search System](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/gate.exe?f=tess&state=4802:reo3r8.1.1) (TESS) and enter search string POKEMON, I get 97 to 100ish results, all in the singular. The search result times out after a while, so you will have to do your own search to verify my results. And if the above link to TESS doesn't work, you can access it through the page [Trademark Database](http://tess2.uspto.gov/).

The [International Trademark Association](http://www.inta.org/Pages/Home.aspx) (INTA) supplies a pdf called "A Guide to Proper Trademark Use for Media, Internet and Publishing Professionals", which you can get at their [Trademark Basics](http://www.inta.org/TrademarkBasics/Pages/TMBasics.aspx) page. This handy publication provides "a few
easy-to-follow rules concerning proper mark use," namely

> When referring to a mark, make sure you pass the “ACID” test of proper use

The **A** in ACID stands for ADJECTIVE. And the publication goes into a lot of blah-blah about why a trademark is a "proper adjective" and not a noun:

> Trademarks and service marks are proper
>   adjectives. Not nouns. Not verbs. A mark should
>   always be used as an adjective qualifying a generic
>   noun that defines the product or service. A
>   mark is a company brand name, not a product or
>   service itself. As adjectives, marks should not be
>   used as plurals or in the possessive form, unless
>   the mark itself is plural or possessive (such as
>   1-800-FLOWERS, MCDONALD’S or LEVI’S).

This advice to the media is actually meant to help a company such as [The Pokémon Company](http://www.pokemon.co.jp/corporate/en/) protect its legal registered trademark. Because if people start nouning it and verbing it, the company risks its trademark/brand name becoming so generic that it becomes difficult for the company to maintain its trademark. Trademarks that have suffered "genericide" include Aspirin, Zipper, Kerosine, Corn Flakes, Elevator, Escolator, Heroin, Thermos, and Yo-Yo.

Xerox put out an ad basically begging people not to use *xerox* as a verb: *If a trademark is misused it could become undone*. See Legal Blog Watch's [Xerox Ad Pretends We Care About Its Trademark Rights to Term 'Xerox'](http://legalblogwatch.typepad.com/legal_blog_watch/2010/06/xerox-ad-pretends-we-care-about-its-trademark-rights-to-term-xerox.html) and also BBC News [Google calls in the 'language police'](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/3006486.stm).

So, I suppose that is why the official sites of Pokémon always (as far as I can see) use it just like that: Pokémon, which is the legal trademark, as a "proper adjective" and not a "proper noun," although The Pokémon Company is not always so careful, straying from the registered trademark in [such a use as](http://www.pokemon.co.jp/corporate/en/business/#international)

> The Pokémon Company and its worldwide affiliates are always striving to increase **Pokémon's popularity** in markets around the world [my emphasis].

It's ironic the next two words are "Brand management."

If you wanna be nice to the company, and also go by the CMOS, always always use only Pokémon and never pokemon. If you don't give a rip, spell it and capitalise it anyway you pleez.

Answer (score 0):

In an informal situation, such as chatting with a friend, you wouldn't capitalize it, but in a situation like writing an essay about it, you must, like all proper nouns.